Iframe does not show the resource if resource location chnged by UseStaticFiles
I want to use an iframe in my Blazor server app to display PDF resources. I have used UseStaticFiles middleware to serve the resource location to iframe, but it does not work.
Here is the code snippets, where test.pdf has been placed in "C:\temp\CRM\Static\temp\pdf\test.pdf" :
Program.cs
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
    {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(@"c:\temp\CRM\Static"),
        RequestPath = "/Static",      
    });

page. Razor
    <iframe src="temp/pdf/test.pdf"></iframe>

Update
Actually my application is placed in c:\temp\CRM\Services directory as builder.Environment.ContentRootPath shows, and the PDF file is placed in c:\temp\CRM\Static\temp\pdf directory.
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions 
{
     FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
          Path.Combine(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath, @"..\Static")),
     RequestPath = "/Static"
});

It means that, I tried to provide a available path to my resource for iframe, but It does not work. It seems that the symbol "..\Static" is not correct.
Update 2
The ".." symbole is now corrected, but it does not work also:
string sContentRootPath = builder.Environment.ContentRootPath;
int idx = sContentRootPath.LastIndexOf("\\");
idx = sContentRootPath.LastIndexOf("\\", idx - 1);
string sContentRoot = sContentRootPath.Substring(0, idx);

app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
     FileProvider = new 
     PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(sContentRoot, "Static")),
     RequestPath = "/Static",

});

Can anyone tell me, what's my mistake?

Thank you K J , I did not used absolutes Path, but I tried to simplfy my issue. Now I describe my issue better in next message.

Now I have found  my mistake and the right answer. With the last update 2, i need to correct ifarme src attribute like this:
<iframe src="/Static/temp/pdf/test.pdf"></iframe>

and it works now.
